# Google Analytics | How to anonymize, without filtering out, all but one traffic source?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm wondering how to anonymize, without filtering out, all but one traffic source.

I have no problem anonymizing all of them, I'm using `.*(.$)` to grab last letter of the traffic Source, and overwriting it to show only the last letter instead of whole traffic source name.

I don't know  how to modify it to ignore all traffic sources that include "facebook" phrase.

Comment: So if you are trying to filter out just Facebook traffic (ie. referral exclusion), then you can take a look at this guide: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034842?hl=en

Comment: I want to anonymize all but Facebook traffic, not exclude it / filter it out.

Comment: Untested, thus as a comment: Use multiple custom advanced filters. Use a regex with brackets to grab the source value if it matches "facebook" and copy it to a custom field. In the next filter overwrite *all* source values. In the third filter grab the custom field if it contains "facebook" and write it to the source field. Works only if the filters are in the correct order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, seems like you cannot do this at all, as the [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034380?hl=en) says you can overwrite *tagged* source, mediums etc. So you would not be able to overwrite at least direct,organic and referral (non-campaign) sources.

The only way around would be if you changed, in your on-page Google Analytics code, the location field before it is submitted to Google Analytics and include utm parameters with dummy values unless the visitor arrives via a facebook campaign.